# WooCommerce - item added to order not actually saved?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I'm trying to make a plugin that merges two carts into one.

I am doing the following:

```
$old_order = wc_get_order($old_order_id);
duplicate_line_items($new_order, $old_order);
//re-fetch order to make sure changes aren't lost.
$new_order = $wc_get_order($new_order->get_id());
$new_order->calculate_totals();
$new_order->save_meta_data();
$new_order->save();
```

My `duplicate_line_items()` function looks like this:

```
function duplicate_line_items($source_order, $new_order){
    foreach ($source_order->get_items() as $item){
        $new_order->add_item($item);
    }
    $new_order->apply_changes();
    $new_order->save();
}
```

When I run this code, the items do not display in the admin view of the "new" order (the destination order), nor do they show up in the database.

I do see that per the `WC_Order::add_item()` docs, "The order item will not persist until save.", but I am saving the order, several times.

Am I missing a step here or something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my issue, I misunderstood the functionality of [`wc_add_order_item()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-wc_add_order_item.html)'s `item_array` parameter, and assumed that was for the item data.

The working function:

```
    /**
     *
     * Copy all line items from
     * 
     * @param $source_order \WC_Order
     * @param $destination_order \WC_Order
     */
    private function duplicate_line_items($source_order, $destination_order){
        //get all item types.
        foreach ($source_order->get_items(['line_item', 'shipping', 'tax']) as $item_id => $item){
            $data = $item->get_data();
            $data['order_id'] = $destination_order->get_id();
            $new_item_id = wc_add_order_item($destination_order->get_id(), ['order_item_name' => $item->get_name(), 'order_item_type' => $item->get_type()]);
            $meta = wc_get_order_item_meta($item_id);
            foreach ($meta as $meta_key => $meta_value){
                //needed incase there are multiple values for the same key: eg, ingredients.
                foreach ($meta_value as $number => $raw_value){
                    wc_add_order_item_meta($new_item_id, $meta_key, $raw_value);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Hopefully this helps someone else later :)

Answer (score 0):

You have your `duplicate_line_items()` function written so that the items from the first parameter, `$source_order` are added to the second parameter, `$new_order`, but in your first block of code you're passing the *old* order as the 2nd parameter:

```
duplicate_line_items($new_order, $old_order);
```

So all the items from `$new_order` are being added to `$old_order`, not the other way round.

Make sure you're using the variables consistently:

```
duplicate_line_items( $old_order, $new_order );
```

Maybe name your variables in `duplicate_line_items()` a bit more clearly too:

```
function duplicate_line_items( $source_order, $target_order ) {
    foreach ( $source_order->get_items() as $item ) {
        $target_order->add_item( $item );
    }

    $target_order->save();
}
```

So with those two changes you're properly setting `$old_order` as the `$source_order` and `$new_order` as the `$target_order`.

Comment: I know it looks confusing, but what's actually being done here is on checkout i'm copying items from the "new" order (aka the "source" order) to the "old" order, aka the target order

Comment: So when you say "the items do not display in the admin view of the "new" order", you mean they don't show up in the _old_ order? Yes, that is confusing...

Comment: They don't no, but I fixed it and posted an answer,